# How do I change default bootstrap navigation on hover?

Tags: css, navigation, hover

I want to style this bootstrap navbar so that an underline shows on hover. I also want to change the colour of the text.

So far I have only managed to change the background colour. Any help would be massively appreciated, apologies for the noob question, I'm fairly new to coding.

Many thanks!

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light" style="background-color:#f7715d">

  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-content" aria- controls="navbar-content" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="<?php esc_html_e( 'Toggle Navigation', 'theme-textdomain' ); ?>">

     <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>

  </button>

</nav>
```

Comment: Please do not tag PHP when your question has nothing to do with it. I've removed the tag from your question

Answer (score 0):

A short css bootstrap example

```
navbar-light {
  background-color:#f7715d;
}

navbar a {
  color: red;
}
```

or you can create custom class and add in to bootstrap class

```
myClass {
  background-color:#f7715d;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light myClass">
```